# Prevent the duplicate function onchange event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selectTest").change(function(e){
    if($(this).val() == "01"){
      $(".show").hide();
    }else{
      $(".show").show();
    };
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="show">
        Sample Text
    </div>
    <select name="test" id="selectTest">
        <option value="00"></option>
        <option value="01">Click this to hide text</option>
        <option value="02">Click this to show text</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Above snippets looks fine, but i am getting trouble when the option where selected from the first when the page loaded. I have to click the different button to make the `hide` function works. I solved that problem by adding the `if ... else` in my code so that when the page loaded the hide function will run properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selectTest").change(function(e){
    if($(this).val() == "01"){
      $(".show").hide();
    }else{
      $(".show").show();
    };
  })

   if($("#selectTest").val() == "01"){
      $(".show").hide();
    }else{
      $(".show").show();
    };
})
```

Above code looks not appropriate because i have to repeat the function that i have made, is there any better way to resolved this problem ?

Comment: Just put that `if/else` block into a function, then you cut down on the duplication. I don't see a better way to do it.

Comment: We can do using the trigger in jquery as explained in one of the Answer said

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of writing code twice, you can trigger the event (*change*) using jQuery's [`.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$("#selectTest").trigger('change');
```

**Working Code Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selectTest").change(function(e){
    if($(this).val() == "01"){
      $(".show").hide();
    }else{
      $(".show").show();
    };
  });
 $("#selectTest").trigger('change');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show">
    Sample Text
</div>
<select name="test" id="selectTest">
    <option value="00"></option>
    <option value="01">Click this to hide text</option>
    <option value="02">Click this to show text</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow, i have never used the `trigger` function, thank you sir, but maybe i will wait for another answer, in case there is a better approach :), but it's resolved my problem.